# connecting the self.managedObjectModel to a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i'm working with core data and navigation controllers. my story board consists of the following: (-> means connected)
 UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> UITableViewController (master view controller) -> UITableViewController (detail view Controller)
Apple's Master-Detail Template offers the following in the appDelegate method application:didFinishLoadingWithOptions which actually work only if the storyboard contain 
UINavigationController -> UITableViewController

`UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;`

`SSViewController *controller = (SSViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;`

`controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;`

this doesn't work in my case because navigation.topViewController will return the UIView Controller. So how can i reach the third view UITableViewController from the application:didFinishLoadingMethod ?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'connected' you mean segues on the storyboard (which is the only logical way I can see to interpret your question), then the answer is that you can't directly.

Instead, you set the property on the `UIViewController` subclass (whatever the default master and/or detail VC is, as appropriate), and pass it on to `UIViewController` subclasses further down the chain in the `prepareForSegue` method.

It's often useful to implement this via a protocol, which appropriate VCs adopt:

```
@protocol ContextHolder <NSObject>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

In `prepareForSegue`, you can then do:

```
((id<ContextHolder>)segue.destinationViewController).managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: ya i mean segues. ok i'll try that now. Thanks.

Comment: I added some more detail to the example.

Comment: prepareForSegue should be placed in the second view control .m file as it is preparing for the uitableview, and the protocol should be place in the .h file of the segue i'm preparing right?

Comment: The `prepareForSegue` method is called on the VC that is preparing the segue.  So if you want to pass from the `UIViewController` to the `UITableViewController`, the method goes on the `UIViewController`.  You would normally put the protocol in its own file, and then adopt it on the `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` (but you could equally just give them a `managedObjectContext` property directly if that's easier)